# Comparing non-deterministic and also the deterministic expressive power of FA, PDA's and TM'S

Tags: computation-theory, deterministic, non-deterministic

I am sorta confused and also could not find a answer online, but in terms of expressive power, *.*

Non-deterministic FA, PDA, TM

```
NFA < NPDA < NTM
```

Deterministic FA,PDA,TM: This is where i am confused

```
DFA < PDA < TM?
```

In a whole: ?

```
DFA = NFA = e-NFA = RE < DPDA < NPDA = NCFL = DCFL < NTM = DTM?
```

Please correct me or am i correct?

Comment: @sungyong Thanks for the edit, now help me out :]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by NCFL and DCFL, but if you replace those two with just "CFG" then what you have is correct, where `=` means "is as powerful as" and `<` means "is less powerful than".

Answer (score 2):

DFA < PDA < TM is correct.

Remember that DFA = NFA = RegEx in power, every NFA can be converted to a DFA which can be converted to RegEx and the other way around.

Context free languages are a little different.
PDA ≠ NPDA. You can construct PDA's for a subset of the context free languages, but you can construct an NPDA for any context free language.

Turing Machines, deterministic and non-deterministics, have equally powerful. Remember that you can simulate any NTM using a single tape DTM.

So in a whole,
DFA = NFA = e-NFA = RE < DPDA < NPDA = NCFL = DCFL < NTM = DTM
is the correct intuition.